# Maven eclipse classpath error

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a project with a standard maven structure (i.e. src/main/java for source code and src/test/java for test code), however when I use mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate the eclipse files the classpath for the main source tree is wrong:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src" including="**/*.java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
```

So the main source path comes out as src rather than src/main/java - is there a reason for this, and can I force it to be correct?

Fixed:
For some reason I had set it in the pom, so the build source was set at /src. I removed that line from the pom and it works fine now

Comment: could you run `mvn help:effective-pom` and see what is configured in `<build>...<sourceDirectory>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eclipse Maven Integration (m2e)](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)
and import as existing Maven project.

Note that you should not perform mvn eclipse:eclipse

NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.